# can i access my Tuya compatible smart devices through API?

Tags: iot, tuya

I am trying to setup a smart energy meter and i plan to store and analyse that data.

In the market ewelink provides options to access my devices through API.

Due to government restrictions, i cannot import a ewelink compatible device. However, devices available in my country are mostly Tuya platform compatible.

I did not find sufficient documentation to see if Tuya compatible devices can be accessed via API or local intranet.

Can i access a Tuya platform device without Tuya App and directly via SDKs or APIs

Alternatively, can i connect a Tuya device to ewelink app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Can i access a Tuya platform device without Tuya App and directly via SDKs or APIs

Yes - if your devices have already been registered in the cloud, and you have the credentials for the account they are registered to, then you can go to https://iot.tuya.com/ and access the devices or get keys which can be used locally with something like https://pypi.org/project/tinytuya/

This may not help you though as the only way I'm aware of to register devices to the tuya cloud is via the app. Registration is a one time process for each device, after which you can use APIs (without the app) to access the devices. Note that there are numerous versions of the tuya app which have been re-branded by the company selling the hardware. Underneath they appear to register devices to the same Tuya cloud.

Note: my experience is with Tuya lightglobes. Smart meters may or may not behave the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
However, would this work as an end user?

Example: I buy a smart device from companyA . Now i can register in the native app of companyA or use the generic app of Tuya. 

In that case will i be able to access my device at iot.tuya.com?

Comment: Yes. A year ago  I purchased some standard retail re-branded Tuya light globes, registered them with app, and using free Tuya accounts I was able to access them via the tuya API.

Comment: @Sahil Ali I'm curious whether you managed to achieve your goal and how. I am facing exactly the same issue and it would seem that every second user of a smart energy meter would love to be able to analyze the data but still I can't seem to find a straightforward solution to this. Am I blind?